# Script for processing huge number of excel files

Tags: python, sql, excel

I have a folder full of 100 excel files. Each excel file is a groundwater station and contains both daily and monthly groundwater data. I want to process data (figure out the monthly average) for each sation and combine them in a seperate excel file. Is it possible to do it with a python script or sql script? Can anybody give me a head start to the script?

Answer (score 2):

you can load each excel file with **pandas** and extract necessary information and then delete the instance(to optimize memory).

when you read all files, you can aggregate all data.

```py
import pandas as pd
excel_list_dir=['one.xlsx','two.xlsx'] # List of excels path(len=100)
ground_water = []
for file_path in excel_list_dir:
    data = pd.read_excel(file_path)
    ground_water.append(sum(data['ground_water_amount']))#Replace with existing column
print(sum(ground_water)/len(ground_water))
```